# problemas com bindValue

Tags: php, pdo

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            (data, sexo)
            VALUES
            (:data,:sexo)";

    $stmt->bindValue(':data', $_REQUEST['data']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sexo', $_REQUEST['sexo']);
```

está dando um erro: `Undefined index: sexo`.
o campo `sexo` é um `radio button` e eu não selecionei ele antes de salvar no banco.
se eu selecionar o campo `sexo`, os dados são salvos normalmente no banco, por que?
queria salvar mesmo se o campo estiver selecionado ou não...

Comment: Bom, o erro é claro e você pareceu entender o motivo. Você está tentando pegar uma informação que não existe, por isso o undefined. Tente verificar se o campo existe com um `if(isset($REQUEST_['campo']))` antes de inserir, se não existir, vc toma uma decisão, como salvar o campo como null ou 0, dependendo de como está a coluna no banco. Leia mais sobre [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

São salvos porque quando você seleciona o campo do tipo radio e envia o POST ao resgatar pela global $_REQUEST este index irá existir.
Quando você não seleciona ele não envia este index: O motivo do erro.
se você quer salvar mesmo sem selecionar coloque um valor como default para salvar no banco. Exemplo:

debug para ferificar os index recebidos pelo formulário
print_r($_REQUEST);

evitar erro de index inexistente
if (!isset($_REQUEST['sexo'])) {
   $sexo = 'seu valor';
}